# Is there a pop-up notepad in TeXstudio?

Tags: texstudio

When I was using TeXstudio, I wrote some long math equations lots of times.

Because it was really tedious works to write them repeatedly, I wrote these equations in the Windows Notepad, and copied and pasted when I needed them.

Since Windows Notepad has no font color like TeXstudio, it is hard to distinguish some similar equations in it.

Thus I wonder there exists a TeXstudio Pop-Up Notepad to make it easy this kinds of work. Or if not, I want to know some other good methods in this situation. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most appropriate for "long math equations [written] lots of times" would be to have `\newcommand{\mycommand}{my long math equation}` in the preamble, so that then you can write `\mycommand` instead of `my long math equation`.  This also has the advantage that you can adjust `\mycommand` once, and the output adjusts everywhere in your document.  And you can parameterize `\mycommand`, so that `\mycommand{A}` and `\mycommand{B}` do slightly different (but very related) things.

The closest to a window with font coloring would be if you open a second TeXstudio window that you use for your scratch work, in addition to your main document.